# Why is Twitter displaying The Authorization Window everytime i try to update status?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, android-twitter

Hi guys i am using the twitter Connect API mentioned in [this](http://javataskforce.com/2012/06/twitter-connect-android/) tutorial But its not working as described there.

The problem that i am facing is that the authorization windows keeps popping up.
The first time it asks for credentials but after that it just opens up a window and when i click authorize it updates my twitter status. SO i was wondering, that can i bypass the annoying Twitter authorize popup that is occurring every time i want to update my twitter status.

I am using this code to check whether twitter is authenticated or not but it always return false

```
if (mTwitter.isAuthenticated()) {
            PostStatus();
        } else {
            mTwitter.authenticate();
        }
```

Comment: You may have to keep the authentication token from OAuth. Check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534254/long-lived-authentication-with-oauth-in-android-app

Comment: I thought this library already implemented that mechanism. Also if i save it explicitly the how will i check that whether the token has expired or not? :/

Comment: May [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) will help you.